# Binding Canvas ZIndexProperty in code behind

Tags: wpf, binding

I want to bind a Control's canvas.zindexproperty to a class property name zindex.

I tried this but it is not working

```
  Binding zIndexBinding = new Binding("zIndex");

        indicator.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, zIndexBinding);
```

i have no idea how to do this, so any help will be appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SetValue` is to set a simple value rather than a binding. You can use instead `SetBinding` when using a `Binding`:

```
indicator.SetBinding(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, zIndexBinding);
```

Be aware that you'll need as well as the `Path`, which you've supplied, a `Source`, `ElementName`, or `DataContext` etc to resolve the object to which the path applies.